# How to set a requiredValue in xml to any value

Tags: xml

Everyone I have a program I am trying to alter.

I need to set the `requiredValue` so that it will recognize any text in the field.  The current value "at1" is simply a test value and not the required value.  We really don't care what's in there so long as there is a value in that field.  The program is a editable format checker for an XML file.  It allows a user to edit the values in the XML file to correct them if they don't match certain requirements.  This particular section doesn't have any particular requirements we  just need to make sure there is something in the field.

```
<general name="" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="container" showTag="true">
    <identifier name="" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" type="container" showTag="true">
        <catalog name="" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                    type="string:1000" requiredValue="at1" showTag="true" />
        <entry name="" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                    type="string:1000" requiredValue="TBD" showTag="true" />
    </identifier>  <!-- Added by edit -->
</general>             <!-- Added by edit -->
```

Comment: With what language do you want to change the attribute value of `requiredValue`? A good choice would be XSLT; but what would your environment permit?

Comment: What is this "program?"  What language?  Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input/edits.  I did figure this out.  I simply removed the required value and the field now seems to recognize when there is text and when there is not.  Of course further testing will need to be completed to ensure it will operate as intended without unintended consequences.